# SQL time period query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timespan

I need to select from a table all rows that have date_added between CURDATE() and 6 weeks ago.

Help please.

Comment: In the future, you should specify that in the question or title (in addition to the tags). Since the different dialects of SQL have varying syntax and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM a_table
WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK) AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   date_added BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 WEEK AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(date_added) <= 42
```

Comment: +1 @Alexander: He wasn't asking how you got the 42, I guess he's a fan of Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (aren't we all :p).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_added)<=42

Answer (score 0):

**if you use dates in one year**

```
select date_format(date, '%u') from tab     
where (date_format(date, '%u')-date_format(now(), '%u'))>6
```

**if you use dates with different years**

you don't have to use dates with another year.
you can use

```
select 
date_format(date, '%u') from tab
where (date_format(date, '%u')-date_format(now(), '%u'))>6
and
date_format(date, '%u') from tab
where (date_format(date, '%Y')-date_format(now(), '%Y'))=0
```

you can optimize query with join if you want. I think you know how to do it